# decompose source data into new, many-to-many schema

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Access 2010 to do some transformations of data.  Specifically, I need to create the data structure for a many-to-many relationship between `concept` (summarized by `rxnconso.rxcui`) and `word` (summarized by `drugwords.id`.  Note that each value of `drugwords.id` needs to correspond with a unique value of `name` from the `words` table in the images below.).  To accomplish this, I need to create two tables, `drugwords` and `drugwordsConsoJunction`, and also decompose the contents of an existing table `words` into the `drugwords` and `drugwordsConsoJunction` tables.  The structure of the destination tables is:

```
drugwords table: (this table needs to be created)  
    id (autonumber pk needs to be created from distinct values of words.name)  
    name  
drugwordsConsoJunction: (this table needs to be created)  
    word_id (fk to drugwords.id)  
    rxcui (fk to rxnconso.rxcui)  
rxnconso (this table already exists):  
    rxcui  
    ...other fields
```

The source table for this transformation is called `words` and has two columns; a value for `rxcui`, and a value for `name`.  As you can see from the images below, there can be many `name` values for a given `rxcui` value.  And the second image below shows that there can be many `rxcui` values for a given `name` value.

**How do I write the SQL to transform words into drugwords and drugwordsConsoJunction, as per the above specifications?**

[image]

[image]

I have uploaded a copy of the database to a file sharing site.  You can download it [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/A35ye5eQVXHSModTO8yO).

Comment: Why do you need an AutoNumber PK on the [drugwords] table when you've already stipulated that the [drugwords].[name] values will be distinct? In other words, if [name] is already a perfectly good PK candidate for [drugwords] then you could just use that as the PK and avoid the junction table altogether.

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, the `word_id` is not necessary because each value of `name` will be distinct.  However, the users will search for `names` LIKE their search term and then, after selecting a `name` that matches their requirement, be directed to a list of all rows that contain their chosen `name` in a more complicated table.  The `rxcui` is the unique key of the more complicated table. So the `words` table above needs to be stripped of its redundancies regardless of whether or not we keep a separate `drugwords` table containing only one field for name.

Comment: How about `SELECT DISTINCT rxcui, [name] INTO drugwordsConsoJunction FROM words` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson I ran that query.  Why does it create 106,000+ rows in `drugwordsConsoJunction` when there are only 72,000+ rows in `words`?  Wouldn't there be fewer rows after eliminating redundancies?

Comment: I have no idea. You are right in thinking that the resulting table should not have *more* rows than then source table. Are you sure about the counts?

Comment: @GordThompson I uploaded the database to a file sharing site and added a link to it at the end of my original posting above.  Yes, I think I am pretty sure about the counts.  Does this help you?

Comment: The [words] table contains 729,123 rows, while the [drugwordsConsoJunction] table contains 106,631 rows.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for catching that.  It sometimes helps to have a second set of eyes looking at a problem.  If you want to post it as an answer, I would be happy to +1 and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the proposed [drugwords] table is already going to have unique values in its [name] column then you don't need an AutoNumber ID column, you can just use the [name] field as a Primary Key. In that case, the table that maps "words" to the corresponding [rxcui] values could be created by simply doing

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT rxcui, [name] INTO drugwordsConsoJunction FROM words
```

Then you can use the "words" themselves instead of introducing another layer of mapping from (distinct) "words" to (distinct) "IDs".

Comment: Thank you.  Your contributions to this site are very much appreciated.

Comment: I have another question related to MS Access.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561904/connecting-eclipse-java-to-odbc-datasource-in-windows-7